# Split large CSV file into multiple files based on the size with the parent file header

Tags: vb.net, csv, ssis

I have a scenario where i have to split a large csv file in multiple csv files and each file should be 100 MB or less in size with the headers.

i have tried below VB.net code in my ssis package, but i am not getting the header row for child files.

please help..

```vb
Public Sub Main()


    Dim FileSize As Integer = 100000   'Specify In KB. Can Be Modified.

    Dim MasterPath As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("Filepath").Value) & "\Master.Csv"

    Dim ChildPath As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("Filepath").Value) & "\Child.Csv"

    Dim LogPath As String = CStr(Dts.Variables("Filepath").Value) & "\Log.Txt"

    Try

        Call SplitFile(MasterPath, ChildPath, LogPath, FileSize)

    Catch Ex As Exception

        MsgBox(Ex.Message)

    End Try

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
Sub SplitFile(ByVal MasterPath As String, ByVal ChildPath As String, ByVal Logpath As String, ByVal SizeKB As Integer)

    Dim FilesizeCounter As Integer

    Dim FileCounter As Integer = 0

    Dim RowCount As Integer = 0

    'Open The Stream And Read It Back.

    Dim Parentsr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(MasterPath)

    Dim Childfs As FileStream

    Dim Logfs As FileStream

    Call CreateFile(Logpath, Logfs)  'Create Log File

    Do While Parentsr.Peek() >= 0    'Looping Master File Stream

        If FilesizeCounter = 0 Then

            FileCounter = FileCounter + 1

            Call CreateFile(Replace(ChildPath, ".Csv", "_" & FileCounter & ".Csv"), Childfs)

        End If

        If FilesizeCounter < (SizeKB * 1024) Then

            Call WriteFile(Childfs, Parentsr.ReadLine() & vbNewLine, FilesizeCounter)

            If Parentsr.EndOfStream Then

                Childfs.Close()

                Call WriteFile(Logfs, "---------", 0)

                Call WriteFile(Logfs, "File Name:" & Replace(ChildPath, ".Csv", "_" & FileCounter & ".Csv") & vbNewLine & "Row Count:" & RowCount & vbNewLine & "Size(Bytes):" & FilesizeCounter & vbNewLine & "Extract End:" & Now().ToString, 0)

            End If

            RowCount = RowCount + 1

        Else

            Call WriteFile(Childfs, Parentsr.ReadLine() & vbNewLine, FilesizeCounter)

            Childfs.Close()   ' Close Child File

            Call WriteFile(Logfs, "---------", 0)

            Call WriteFile(Logfs, "File Name:" & Replace(ChildPath, ".Csv", "_" & FileCounter & ".Csv") & vbNewLine & "Row Count:" & RowCount & vbNewLine & "Size(Bytes):" & FilesizeCounter & vbNewLine & "Extract End:" & Now().ToString, 0)

            RowCount = RowCount + 1

            FilesizeCounter = 0    ' Reset File Size Counter

        End If

    Loop

    Parentsr.Close()  ' Close Master File

    Logfs.Close()     ' Close Log File

End Sub

Sub CreateFile(ByVal Path As String, ByRef Fs As FileStream)

    If File.Exists(Path) Then File.Delete(Path)  'Delete The If Already Exist.

    Fs = File.Create(Path)

End Sub
Sub WriteFile(ByRef Fs As FileStream, ByVal LineInfo As String, ByRef FilesizeCounter As Integer)

    Dim Info As Byte() = New Text.UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(LineInfo & vbNewLine)

    Fs.Write(Info, 0, Info.Length)    ' Add Some Information To The File.

    FilesizeCounter = FilesizeCounter + Info.Length

End Sub


#Region "ScriptResults declaration"

'This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
'result of the script.

'This code was generated automatically.
Enum ScriptResults
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum

#End Region

End Class
```

i need to include master file headers into child files.

Comment: I don't see anyplace where you're reading the first line from `Parentsr`. That's what you need to do. Read that first line, and then every time you create a new file, write it before you write anything else.

Comment: Thank you Scott,but i have to skip the first child file and write to all other files.

Comment: Are you working with a single file format? That is, will the columns and datatypes always be the same?

Comment: thank you Scott hannen. i have figured it out.

@aaron: yes it is the single file format and all the columns and datatypes always be the same

Answer (score 0):

I have read the header from parentsr

```
Dim header as string = parentsr.readline()
```

then i am writing it back when i create the child files

```
Call WriteFile(Childfs, header & vbNewLine, FilesizeCounter)
```